# Transpose only one level of a pandas MultiIndex dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to reformat a DataFrame, turning values in a row into columns. I tried using melt but just got errors. Transpose seemed to get me part of the way there, but gave weird output (because the input was a grouped DataFrame I think)

```
d = {'name':['bil','bil','bil','jim'],
     'col2': ['acct','law', 'acct2','law'],
     'col3': [1,2,3,55]
    }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2.groupby(['name','col2']).agg({'col3':'first'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
name    col2      col3
bil     acct        1
        acct2       3
        law         2
jim     law        55
```

GOAL:

```
     acct acct2 law
bill 1     3     2
jim              55
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `first` directly. Also, you'll need `unstack` with a custom `fill_value`:

```
(df2.groupby(['name', 'col2'])['col3']
    .first()
    .unstack(fill_value='')
    .rename_axis(None, 1))

     acct acct2 law
name               
bil     1     3   2
jim              55
```

Comment: That works perfectly for the example, but is there a way to write that without the dot syntax? It causes errors in my actual dataset, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506390/python-pandas-series-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: @Rilcon42 Sure, take a look now?